# How do I know connected socket.io client which transport is being used websocket or polling?

Tags: socket.io

Is there a way that I can know the connected socket.io client which transport is using? e.g. websocket / polling

I am using "socket.io-client": "2.0.1" +  "socket.io": "2.0.1"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
        console.log(socket.conn.transport.name);
});
```

Client:

```
socket.io.engine.transport.name
```

Comment: that does not work, but this is working: socket.io.engine.transport.name